# RabbitMQ listen on port 25672 after activating new NIC interface

Tags: networking, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ and it worked correctly until I activate a new NIC interface and it changed the port for IPV4 to 25672. Here is the output of `netstat -nlpt` | grep 5672

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      971/beam.smp        
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      971/beam.smp
```

On the IPV6 it listens on port 5672 but on IPV4 it listens to 25672. Surprisingly the process on the remote nodes can connect to IP:5672 but the process that is running on the node in which the RabbitMQ process is running, too, cannot connect to it!

How can I solve the problem?
Is any way to specify IP for RabbitMQ to listen to instead of 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux (by default) treats IPv4 as a special case
of IPv6, so by listening on all IPv6 addresses we are also listening on
all IPv4 ones.

Don't forget to allow to port with ufw allow 5672/tcp